# University asking for documents I just uploaded online

Tags: graduate-admissions

I just applied to University online (since that is the only way to apply). However, they say we must get previous Universities to mail them official transcripts, but everything else is done online.

Before pressing `Validate` and `Submit` button, I checked and rechecked (several times) whether I filled in everything and included

1. Three letters of recommendation
2. Current resume
3. Statement of purpose.

Then I submitted the application online and get confirmation email that says

> Please submit the following required documents to complete your
>   application:
>
> 1. Official University Transcripts
> 2. Two Letters of Recommendation
> 3. Resume or Curriculum Vitae
> 4. Statement of Purpose
> 5. GRE or GMAT (if applicable)
> 6. TOEFL, IELTS, CAE, or PTE Academic (if applicable)

Ok, I understand I have get previous Universities to send official transcripts, but why is it asking for letters of recommendation, resume, and statement of purpose again?

Is this simply a canned response?

My question: How inform graduate admissions that I uploaded letters of recommendation, resume, and statement of purpose online, and to confirm whether they received it.

Please advise.

Answer (score 6):

Don't overthink this.  Just send them an email and ask.

Comment: Ok, I just emailed them